# SFINAE using VoidT with different compilers leads to different results

Tags: c++

Consider the following code:

```
template <typename T> using VoidT = void;

class A {
public:
   using TEST = int;
};

class C {
public:
   using DIFFERENT = int;
};

template <typename T, typename Enable = void>
class B {
public:
   B() = delete;
};

template <typename T>
class B<T, VoidT<typename T::TEST>> {
public:
   B() = default;
};

template <typename T>
class B<T, VoidT<typename T::DIFFERENT>> {
public:
   B() = default;
};

int main() {
   B<A> a;
   B<C> b;

   return 0;
}
```

Using g++-4.8.5, compiling this code gives me the following error message:

```
~/test/compile_test> g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp

test.cpp:31:7: error: redefinition of ‘class B<T, void>’

test.cpp:24:7: error: previous definition of ‘class B<T, void>’
```

However, when I compile using g++-8.3 (in, e.g., ideone) the code compiles and the different specializations are treated correctly. Was this a bug in GCC that was fixed, or am I somehow invoking undefined behavior (and therefore the difference in compiler behavior is a moot point - it's undefined)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Was this a bug in GCC that was fixed?

It was a defect in the standard. It was fixed retroactively for previous standard versions, but of course only newer compiler versions will have the fix. It was [CWG Issue 1558](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1558), and to quote from it:

> The treatment of unused arguments in an alias template specialization
>   is not specified by the current wording of 17.6.7 [temp.alias]. For
>   example:
>
> ```
>   #include <iostream>
>
>   template <class T, class...>
>     using first_of = T;
>
>   template <class T>
>     first_of<void, typename T::type> f(int)
>       { std::cout << "1\n"; }
>
>   template <class T>
>     void f(...)
>       { std::cout << "2\n"; }
>
>   struct X { typedef void type; };
>
>   int main() {
>     f<X>(0);
>     f<int>(0);
>   }
> ```
>
> Is the reference to first_of with T being int
>   equivalent to simply void, or is it a substitution failure?

The workaround for compilers without the DR fix is to use a helper:

```
template<typename T> struct voider { using type = void; };
template <typename T> using VoidT = typename voider<T>::type;
```

Substitution failure is guaranteed in a class template.

Comment: Retroactive fixes bother me. It means there's never a canonical document describing any version of the language.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I see your point. One can hope that such retroactive fixes are reserved only for valid constructs that should not be rejected, so the harm is minimal.

Comment: @StoryTeller Indeed.